# Small Caps in Java

Tags: java, smallcaps

To change letters to Upper Case, there's `.toUpperCase()`. To change letters to Lower Case, there's `.toLowerCase()`.

Is there a way for the words to appear in small caps?

(Small caps are uppercase with a lower font height, and some fonts have a special set of design for it.)

Comment: What method are you using for displaying text? You can't have small caps in a `String`; that's a font/rendering thing.

Comment: can you provide some code so I can have a better understanding of your situation?

Comment: what code are you using to display the text? in Java the simplest method is to use the font that already uses smallcap for lower case. if you are displaying the text by rendering a webpage, CSS can be used to create the effect with "font-variant: small-caps;"

Comment: Wikipedia article on small caps: https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Small_caps

Answer (score 1):

Smallcaps is a font property -  java is basically blind  to it. So just  convert case on java side as you like, and use proper fornts on the frontend side ( CSS in a web page for example )

Comment: Wrong, there are Unicode characters for it. But no built-in function, I'm afraid.

Answer (score 0):

A `String` is always just a `String`. It contains no data about what font-height it has or anything like that. Smallcaps are really just a display-thing. The only way I see to get the SmallCaps info into a string is if you muckle about with a strange Locale and use some `toUpperCase(yourStrangeLocale)` (https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/lang/String.html#toUpperCase-java.util.Locale-). But even so, you would be mixing display-properties with 'raw' data properties.

Your best way forward, in my opinion, is basically to do `string.toUpperCase()` and then for every sentence do `.charAt(0)` and increase the font-size for that char.

---

**Edit as unicode was mentioned in the comments.**

If your system supports unicode, then you can simply input the unicode-chars for your text as unicode actually defines separate chars for these. Java *still* don't have any method to get these chars as they hold no extra meaning rather than emphasis, just like italics and bold don't hold any value in a `String`.

What you can do, if you don't want to capitilize and change font-size, is write your own `String toSmallCaps(String input)` method inwhere you go char-for-char and replace it with its unicode-smallcaps counterpart. Here's a list for the codes: http://www.calcresult.com/reference/text/unicode-list.html

Comment: Unicode supports smallcaps symbols, and it's not "just a display-thing" : `String a = "Sᴍᴀʟʟᴄᴀᴘs"; System.out.println(a);`.

Comment: Nice. Learned something new today.

Comment: @FlorentBayle You can also do `final String str = "\uD835\uDC01\uD835\uDC0E\uD835\uDC0B\uD835\uDC03\n"; System.out.println(str);` but I wouldn't say that it means that bold has any other value that being a 'display-thing'.